# tableview expand and collapse with an array of category -> sub category -> sub sub category like that

Tags: swift

**i've tried  and got result with category -> sub category, but when i tried with sub sub category i failed.**

`func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return getPriceList.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if getPriceList[section].isOpened == true{
            return getPriceList[section].subService!.count+1
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let subCategoryIndex = indexPath.row - 1
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_ID.JF_PRICE_LIST_CELL, for: indexPath) as! PriceListCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = getPriceList[indexPath.section].serviceName
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2613176107, green: 0.2559443712, blue: 0.2659199238, alpha: 1)
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_ID.JF_PRICE_LIST_CELL, for: indexPath) as! PriceListCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = getPriceList[indexPath.section].subService?[subCategoryIndex].subServiceName
        cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2790801227, green: 0.6332188845, blue: 0.4609255791, alpha: 0.8018487966)
        return cell
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        if getPriceList[indexPath.section].isOpened == true{
            getPriceList[indexPath.section].isOpened = false
            let sections = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)
        }else{
            getPriceList[indexPath.section].isOpened = true
            let sections = IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .fade)

        }
    }
}`
```

[i want like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcjE3.jpg)

Comment: please don't suggest dependencies.. thank you

Comment: Don't worry, no-one possibly can. You just pasted some code without any explanation or an actual question.

Comment: @VasuYarasu please refer this link :-https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-how-to-build-a-table-view-with-collapsible-sections-96badf3387d0